# Is there a way to use custom soundfonts/soundbanks with winmm?

Tags: midi, fasm, winmm, mcisendstring, soundfont

Is there a way to use custom soundfonts/soundbanks while playing MIDI files with winmm.dll or do I have to use something else to do that? (I'm trying to do it in FASM).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default synthesizer, "Microsoft GS Wavetable SW Synth", uses the file `gm.dls`, which is a system file and should not be replaced. There is no programmatic way to choose another sound font.